# friendly urls for users profile?

Tags: php, apache, url, friendly-url

hello i wanted to create a format for users url, for example for the user ninja123, he would get a profile link of example.com/ninja123,  im using php mysql on apache. this is the normal link!

```
viewprofile.php?userid=2
```

how could i appraoch this problem? and im a bad .htaccesss newbie :)) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing `$_GET['userid']` and looking for ID... switch it by looking for name so it's like: `viewprofile.php?userid=Ninja123`

Try this Mod Rewrite generator: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

Create a .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If a site visitor requests `http://example.com/Ninja123`, the folder won't be found so it will run `index.php` and fill `$_GET['url']` with `/Ninja123`

In index.php, grab the path component from `$_GET['url']`:

```
$username = trim(parse_url($_GET['url'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
```

Now $username will contain `Ninja123`. You can use that to do a database search to retrieve the user id. If you want this to work with requests that contain sub-directories (example.com/Ninja123/photos/party) you'll want to strip out those sub-directories before performing the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a .htaccess RewriteRule only for this. If the forum exposes database internal IDs, you have mostly to rewrite parts of the SQL query. Basically you need to accept `$_GET["username"]` instead of `"userid"` first, and then rewrite the lookup. As example:

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?", (int)$_GET["userid"]);
```

to

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?", encode($_GET["username"]));
```

Depends on the application, the actual SQL table structure, and the DB interface (your forum probably uses `mysql_query` and `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `encode`).

After that you can deploy a simple `RewriteCond !-f {%..}` and `RewriteRule (.+) /viewprofile?username=$1` to get short URLs.