# Custom URL for user profile page

Tags: php, mysql, url

I have a basic PHP script that displays a user's profile information from a MySQL database in a simple format. Currently, to view a profile you enter the following link:

```
https://xxx.xxx.com/profile.php?id=XXX
```

However, what I'd like is something similar to Twitter, where the URL looks more like:

```
https://xxx.xxx.com/profile/UserName
```

I have already read [friendly urls for users profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601937/friendly-urls-for-users-profile), but that suggested to use:

```
https://xxx.xxx.com/profile.php?username=UserName
```

...which is not what I'd like. Is there any way this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: Read up about "URL rewrites"  .. and probably "single point of entry".

Comment: You are looking for URL rewriting, if you are using apache have a look here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html, http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: Thanks. Is there any simple way to do URL rewrites on a 1&1 hosting plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code
your .htaccess file will contain this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/$    index.php    [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    profile.php?username=$1    [NC,L]    
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Note : from where you are giving the link just put the link as 
http://example.com/profile/username

If your username contains spaces,strings then url will not be clean so make sure user name must not contain any special character or spaces

for removing and getting clean string use below function

```
function to_prety_url($str)
{
    if($str !== mb_convert_encoding( mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32') )
        $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str));
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace('`&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig);`i', '\1', $str);
    $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace(array('`[^a-z0-9]`i','`[-]+`'), '-', $str);
    $str = strtolower( trim($str, '-') );
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 'daker' for replying. To answer my own question, I need to use URL rewrites. For anyone else looking for how to do this, I suggest looking at https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners, which offers a comprehensive beginner-friendly guide. Also, I did a Google search for 'rewrite generator', and used one to generate a rewrite that worked for me.